# Story identification - A BBC Radio 4 parody of The Prisoner

Tags: story-identification, radio-play, the-prisoner

I heard this on BBC Radio 4 back in the 1990's.

It was a comedy parody of the show The Prisoner. The protagonist was Number 96 (As numbers were given based on importance, he was very unimportant) in The Village.

There was a running joke about him changing his badge and pretending to be number 69 to chat up women, and subsequently trying to avoid the 'Big bloke' who was the real 69.

He was also trying to find out why he was there and trying to escape - like Patrick McGoohan, but being generally inept.

I can't remember if this was a short series or just a single episode.

Thanks.

Comment: You *might* possibly find it on [this list](http://www.theunmutual.co.uk/newsarchive.htm) ...

Comment: No sign of it there I'm afraid. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 5):

I haven't actually heard it, but could this what you are looking for?

> In the radio version of impressionist show Dead Ringers, a version of The Prisoner is set within the radio soap opera The Archers. In it, Ambridge is the Village, Joe Grundy is Number 2, and Ruth Archer is Number 1. — [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Prisoner_in_popular_culture)

Comment: I remember hearing that sketch, but that's not the one I remember. I think it predates the Dead Ringers radio show. Thanks anyway.

Comment: No prob. I'll keep looking, but so far the answer is making itself scarce.

Comment: Don't worry. All help is good. Just trying to find proof that it wasn't a fever dream or something. Thanks.